Objective C - freopen command creates file but does not redirect output
I'm using the following lines in my app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to attempt to redirect NSLog output to a file. This is code that's in many SO answers.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mylog.txt"];
freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation],"a+",stderr);

The file is getting created, but it's empty. Also, from what I understand this should stop the NSLog messages from appearing in the Xcode console but they still show up.
All help appreciated.

I assume you based that code on an SO answer from 2011? I believe that Xcode 15 no longer captures stderr to show NSLog entries, and instead gets it from the system log.  So you could argue that the output is already going to file...

I've seen that code used in answers up to 2020 or so.  So, do you know of any other way of redirecting NSLog to a file I designate on the phone?

No, you would need to write your own logger code.

The following source code creates a C function called MyLog().  You would need to include this function inline in your project and call it just like you would NSLog(), ie MyLog(@"Some text."); . Multiple strings from this function are then written to your log file by adding an NSMutableArray.
NSMutableArray *strings; // At the top of your app

void MyLog( NSString *formatString, ... ) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, formatString );
    
    NSString *format = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n", formatString];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
    [strings addObject:string];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mylog.txt"];
    NSString *arrayStr = [strings componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSData* data = [arrayStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logPath contents:data attributes:nil];
    
    va_end( ap );
}

Initialize the function with 'strings = [NSMutableArray array];' called at the beginning of your app // eg in AppDelegate's  -applicationDidFinishLaunching: method 

Alternative method to remove 'logPath' code from logging function:
NSMutableArray *strings;
NSString *logPath; // At the top of your app

void MyLog( NSString *formatString, ... ) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, formatString );
    
    NSString *format = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n", formatString];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
    [strings addObject:string];
    NSString *arrayStr = [strings componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSData* data = [arrayStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logPath contents:data attributes:nil];
    
    va_end( ap );
}

Use AppDelegate's method -applicationDidFinishLaunching to initialize NSMutableArray and obtain the logPath:
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
 strings = [NSMutableArray array];
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mylog.txt"];
}



I didn't downvote your answer, but I can see why someone might have.  This is terribly expensive logging code.  Firstly open the log file once per process, not every log call.  Secondly what's going on with that format string?

@trojanfoe Thank you for your comments.  The format string is merely to add a line feed so that the entries don't run together; each is on a separate line.  I will edit the answer to add an NSMutableArray so that it will trap multiple entries.  I couldn't tell from the initial post how many strings were involved.
